# PHP using date() function to get numeric value for Sunday - Saturday

Tags: php

I am trying to get a numeric value (0-6) for the last day of the week in the month however it keeps returning a value of 3 when it in fact should be 4 for the month of 05-2018. Am I going about this in the wrong manner?

```
$endMonth = date('Y-m-t');
$dayPostition = date('w', $endMonth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a string, not a date... try this

```
$endMonth = date('Y-m-t');
$dayPostition = date('w', strtotime($endMonth));
```

Comment: Late again, you all are so quick!

Comment: Good god! I didnt even think about that haha. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the last on current month, you can:

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('w');
```

Or using a specific date

```
$date = new DateTime("2018-05-01"); //May 1, 2018
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('w');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second parameter of **[`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** must be a timestamp rather than a string, and `date()` *itself* simply returns a string.

As such, you need to explicitly convert the first `date()` to a timestamp with **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**:

```
$testvar = date('Y-m-t');
$lastDay = date('w', strtotime($testvar));
```

Which can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/LM1d9)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last day of month, you can use cal_days_in_month()

> This function will return the number of days in the month of year for
>   the specified calendar."
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.

Try this

```
$getlastday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 05, 2018);
$endMonth = date('2018-05-'.$getlastday);
$dayPostition = date('w', strtotime($endMonth));
```

Comment: Another great solution as well. Thank you

Comment: Your Welcome :) Happy to help